# jQuery hover issue if mouse moves fast

Tags: jquery, events, hover

I have `div` with class `.catalog-btn`. It has sibling `.catalog-mnu` (dropdown menu) with `display: none`

When I `hover` on `.catalog-btn`, `slideDown()` is triggered for `.catalog-mnu`.

`.catalog-mnu` appears under`.catalog-btn`. It has `:before` pseudo-class which creates `div` with width and height equal to size of `.catalog-btn`. So what happens: user hover on button, dropdown menu appears, this menu has `before` element which covers hovered button. So now button is covered with dropdown menu `.catalog-mnu`. If `mouseleave` triggered for dropdown-menu, `slideUp()` will hide it.
Here is HTML:

```
<div class="catalog-btn">
    <div class="catalog-btn__text">Каталог оборудования</div>
</div>
<div class="catalog-mnu">
    <ul>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is jQuery code:

```
  $(document).on('mouseenter', '.catalog-btn', function() {
    $(".catalog-mnu.catalog-mnu-desktop").stop().slideDown(250);
  });

  $(document).on('mouseleave', '.catalog-mnu.catalog-mnu-desktop', function() {
    $(".catalog-mnu.catalog-mnu-desktop").stop().slideUp(250);
  });
```

The **problem** is: if you will hover button, but will move mouse out really fast, before `slideDown()` animation is finished, dropdown menu will appear, but there will be no `"mouseenter"` on dropdown-menu. So cursor is not on dropdown menu but menu is visible (while it should be visible only on hover). Menu wont hide until you actually hover it and then move mouse out.

How can I change jQuery code to solve this puzzle? I guess that problem is in animation. When you hover on button - `slideDown()` starts. But if `mouseleave` happens before animation is finished - `'mouseenter'` event is not triggered. If don't move cursor fast - everything works as expected.

Comment: If the elements are siblings, then you can achieve this in CSS alone, which will avoid all the JS related performance issues. If you'd like an example of how to do this, could you please add your HTML to the question

Comment: You can solve this by using css animations

Comment: Added HTML to post. But i think i've got your idea, i will try to do this with pure CSS

Comment: Thanks for editing to include your HTML. I added an answer for you below with an example of how to do this in CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JS tends to have issues like this on mouse events where the mouse moves quickly. An alternative is to use CSS to animate the menu state using the `:hover` pseudo selector and the `transition` property, which can be done like this in your case:

```css
.catalog-mnu {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.catalog-btn:hover + .catalog-mnu,
.catalog-mnu:hover {
  max-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="catalog-btn">
  <div class="catalog-btn__text">Каталог оборудования</div>
</div>
<div class="catalog-mnu">
  <ul>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
    <li>Link</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move **catalog-mnu** inside your **hover**.

I suggest you do not use slideDown/SlideUp in this case, and implement your own animation... something like this:

```
.menu-outer {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

<div class="catalog-btn">
  <div>BUTTON</div>
  <div class="menu-outer"><div class="menu-inner">MENUITEM<br/>MENUITEM<br/>MENUITEM</div></div>
</div>

$(document).on('mouseenter', '.catalog-btn', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.find('.menu-outer').stop(true, false).animate({'height': $this.find('.menu-inner').outerHeight()}, 250, 'swing', function() {
    $this.find('.menu-outer').css({'height': 'auto'});
  });
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '.catalog-btn', function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.find('.menu-outer').stop(true, false).animate({'height': 0}, 250, 'swing', function() {
    $this.find('.menu-outer').css({'height': ''});
  });
});
```